# Override TD:first-child with TR:hover?

Tags: css, hover, css-selectors

I have a table where the first cells have a different background.  When the TR:hover is applied those cells do not change.

Is there a way to override them when the row is hovered?

```
#spreadsheet TABLE, #spreadsheet TH, #spreadsheet TD { 
  border:1px solid #CCC;
}

#spreadsheet TABLE TR:hover { 
  background:#BAFECB !important;
}

#spreadsheet TD:first-child { 
  background:#fff; 
  white-space:nowrap; 
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

try

```
#spreadsheet TABLE TR:hover TD { background:#BAFECB !important; }
```

Yep, it works.

Code: http://jsfiddle.net/b9ndZ/1/

Comment: Works without !important too!

Comment: @jerrygarciuh: The problem is not with `!important`, it's with `tr` and `td`. You don't need `!important` at all.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that the `td` elements are nested in the `tr` element, which means that `td`'s background will be "above" the `tr`'s background.

To let the `td`s "loose" their background you have at least two options:

**One**: http://jsfiddle.net/mqchen/WXvkk/
Using the `:not()` pseudo selector you can set the `td`'s background only when the user isn't hovering over the `tr`. Downside with this is that `:not()` only works in some browsers (IE) if you use e.g. http://selectivizr.com/

```
table tr:not(:hover) td:first-child {
    background-color: #eee;
}

table tr:hover {
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

**Two**: http://jsfiddle.net/mqchen/zPGW9/
Set the `td`'s background color to be transparent when it's parent `tr` is hovered over.

```
table td:first-child {
    background-color: #eee;
}

table tr:hover td:first-child {
    background-color: transparent;
}

table tr:hover {
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

The advantage of these solutions vs. that by Samich is that this will also work where the parent element's background not a solid color, eg. a graphic, gradient, etc.

Comment: Thank you.  I feel like I understand the problem much better now. I appreciate your time in make a thorough explanation!